# iOS setDateFormat bug with displaying hour

Tags: ios, date-format

I have a code like this:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
dateHM = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

I use dateHM (`NSString`) in stringWithFormat:, and i expected to always have it displayed as for example 23:00, not 11:00. It works right almost every time, but some app users are getting 12-hours format with AM/PM added...

How is that possible? Does global user preferences make a difference, or what?

Comment: Are you setting a locale on your date formatter or letting it do its own thing?

Comment: I don't set it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn all about date formatters and how they interact with `NSLocale` by reading this Apple [tech note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html).